# Best Site for question about currency symbols?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask about best practice regarding usage of the currency symbol for the British Pound Sterling (£), but I'm not sure which site to post on.

The are the questions I want to ask:

1. Aside from other formats, is the British Pound Sterling typically written as `UK£` or `GB£`?
2. For this hybrid format, what is typically used prior to the currency symbol: the ISO country code, the internationally standardised abbrev. for the region, or is there no standardised format?

On the one hand, it is about common conventions with *writing*, so perhaps EL&U would be best.
On the other hand, it is about *currency* formats, which may be better understood by economists.

However, I can't post in Economics because its site description is "For professional and academic economists and analysts", neither of which I am.

Any idea where I should post?

Comment: Best practice? BEST PRACTICE? IIRC 95% of best practices are being hammered these days.

Comment: What? Dude, I'm just asking. You don't have to yell at me.

Comment: Not yelling. That's an attempt at a joke. Seriously though, is that literally the body of your question?

Comment: Not sure how I feel about that joke, but okay. Thanks for not seriously yelling. Lol. And what? Yes? Why do you ask? :/

Comment: "best practice" - that is meaningless without context. How to use the symbol **where**? To convey **what**? Simply to "use it" means nothing.

Comment: Just a heads-up: I'll be the first to admit that EL&U is a bit inconsistent when it comes to questions of style and writing conventions. Some questions are well-received and others get closed as POB (with the site skewing to the latter response in recent years).

Comment: [International Currency Formatting Guidelines — Currency Codes](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/9105)?

Comment: [Where to place currency symbol when localizing and what to do with odd symbols](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/22574)?

Comment: @Oded: Really? -_- It's a freaking *currency symbol*; **where else** would I be using it other than to refer to currency??

Comment: @DanBron: Thanks for mentioning that; I'll keep that in mind. And "POB"?

Comment: @SarahofGaia Shorthand for "Primarily Opinion Based", subjective. Spelling and word-meanings are standardized to the extent that questions on them can be definitively settled with reference to a dictionary. Many grammatical questions can be too (with reference to a grammar). But orthographic and stylistic questions are harder to answer definitively, it's often a matter of taste: there is no standard reference. So many such questions get closed for being too subjective.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Those two links don't tell me what I need to know.

Comment: @SarahofGaia It was worth a punt, given how little you told us about what you were trying to find out ... :/

Comment: @DanBron: Oh, okay. So what site would be best, then? I want to ask about a single, specific currency, so country-relativity wouldn't really be an issue. And I'd specify it's common practice I'm asking about, which means it's not a subjective question at all, but merely one of statistics.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Hey, I'm not criticising you. It was very helpful. Thank you. :)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Also, I thought I was pretty specific. I don't want to ask the question here, since it annoys me how often people try to answer the question here. I'm not asking you all what the answer is, merely where I can ask the question.

Comment: @SarahofGaia If you frame it that way and make it as specific as possible, I think EL&U is the best fit. The only other places I can think of are Writers, but they're more comfortable answering questions about citation style and art of the written word, Tex/LaTex, but I imagine they'd be better at explaining *how* to achieve a specific goal in formatting, as opposed to offering guidance into *what* goal is appropriate, and maybe Academia, because those guys write a lot of formal papers (and answer questions about how to write formal papers). But I really think ELU is best-fit.

Comment: @DanBron: Ah, I see. Well, thank you very much. ^_^

Comment: @SarahofGaia Then try http://english.stackexchange.com. There are already questions there about "currency symbol" http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=currency+symbol

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting the question content here if you really want us to tell you where to go and have it be correct.

Comment: @Catija: Fair enough. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: [What does a “normal” British pound sign look like?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19181/30494)

Comment: Oh dear, fine. I'll edit my question to include what I find out.

Comment: Also, @Loong, thanks for the link. Unfortunately, that's not what I wanted to find out. Thank you, though.

Comment: There. I stated my questions in the question.

Answer (score 4):

ELU isn't about *writing*, it's about the [English Language and its use](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I'm not saying it's **not** on topic there, mainly clearing up their subject. There is a Beta "[Writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)" site, which is why I'm making the distinction.

As to Economics, every site is technically for professionals... but that doesn't mean you can't ask questions there if you are not one.

I'm a user of ELU but not Economics, so I can't guess what the latter will do... and ELU is a bit odd, so I honestly can't guess what they'd do, either.

I'd start by asking on the Metas for these two sites whether the users of those sites consider the question on-topic or not.

You've got it narrowed down to two, it's up to the individual sites to decide if it's on-topic or not. If you don't want to double post on the Metas, you can always go for your top choice first and then try the second one if you get shot down.

Comment: Also, people keep saying EL&U is odd. What is so odd about it?

Comment: @Sarah You have to see that for yourself. It's unexplainable.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M: Okay.